# Set properties on a data source reference during deployment on websphere

Tags: database, web-applications, websphere, datasource

We have a data source reference defined in our web application, running on websphere application server 8.5. We would like to define custom properties on the reference (I.e. not the actual data source, but the reference, so we can define properties with an application scope). I have figured out how to do this in the WAS admin console UI. However, I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to specify these properties in the deployment descriptor  (I.e. the .xmi file). Is this possible? If so how do I do it? Or do you have to use wsadmin to configure it after deployment?

Edit: to clarify, here is a link the describes setting properties via the admin console UI
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Ftdat_heteropool.html